# Uninstalling Sync Framework without breaking Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-sync-framework

Not strictly programming-related, but I do not know where else to post this question: Is Sync Framework a truly indispensable component of Visual Studio 2010?

From what I read about the Sync Framework, it is a tool that helps developers "synchronize data across multiple data stores," (Quoted text literally taken from [Wikipedia's article on Sync Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework)) a task that does not seem to be central to Windows, .NET Framework or Visual Studio.

Since none of my programming activities involves anything remotely resembling such a thing as "synchronizing data across multiple data stores," I thought it would be best to uninstall Sync Framework, especially taking into account the fact I am running out of disk space on my Windows dev box. However, when I tried to uninstall Sync Framework, a warning appeared that Visual Studio depends on it, and thus might not work correctly if I uninstall it.

So, without further ado: May I uninstall Sync Framework without breaking Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio project item Local Database Cache uses Sync Framework.

If you're not going to use that project item, then I guess you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Besides the Local Database Cache, what *else* uses the sync framework?