# Uninstall Sync Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to clean up my system a bit, and came across two entries related to either Visual Studio 2005, 2008, or 2010:

```
Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 Core Components
Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 Provider Services
```

I do not currently, and will not in the future, be using the Sync Framework. Can they be safely uninstalled without affecting other Visual Studio components?  If not, which components may be affected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstalling Sync Framework without breaking Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631368/uninstalling-sync-framework-without-breaking-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the same question as this one: [Uninstalling Sync Framework without breaking Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631368/uninstalling-sync-framework-without-breaking-visual-studio)

Visual Studio's Local Database Cache project item uses Sync Framework.

Comment: Yep, it is; must have missed that question. Thanks.